# Enter EDL mode in Motorola devices

Tags: unbricking, motorola, motorola-moto-e

I have a bricked Motorola Moto E (2nd gen) XT1527 which throws a preflash validation failed error whenever I try to flash any of the files included in the stock firmware. Some guy told me to enter EDL mode, and I would prefer not to disassemble the device.

Searching through the internet, I found a way to enter EDL mode with a modified fastboot.exe, but it seems to work only for Xiaomi devices.

Is there some way to do this in Motorola devices? USB debugging and OEM unlock are disabled, and the bootloader is locked.

Comment: These days no new phone will allow you to trigger EDL via key combos or a custom fastboot. Not even Xiaomi. Disassembly will be your only way to enter EDL.

Comment: @singhnsk do you know where can I find the pins in order to access edl mode in moto devices? I have dissasembled the phone but can't find them and every tutorial I find is for xiaomi devices. Do you know how the pins look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can always make an EDL cable.  Simply take a usb cable you want, take the top layer off to expose the wires.  Usually they are color coded, and if so, strip the black and green cables, but keep them separated.  Use a PUSH switch between the green and black cable, so when pressed, it will SHORT the black and green cables, thus throwing the device into EDL mode.

To activate EDL mode, some devices use different method.  Power the device off, plug the cable into the phone computer.

Method 1

plug the cable into the phone and when the battery status shows, press the button.  The device should reboot.  Most devices will blink the led red when in EDL mode.

method 2

press the button to short the cables and keep it pressed while you connect the phone.  The phone should start EDL mode and blink the led.

Hope that helps.